# calling a function in sql within nested loop

Tags: postgresql

My query doesnt even work, but hopefully the logic comes through.  Basically Im using datavault.dimdates_csv to produce a row for each date/day.  Then for each day Im trying to get all account ids and for each and call a function using the date and for the account.

is there a better approach to getting my data?  I know nested loops arnt that great for sql.

```
 do
$$
declare
    date_record record;
    account record;
begin
    for date_record in select d."date"  from datavault.dimdates_csv d
    for account in select sad.id from datavault.sat_account_details sad 
    select datavault.account_active_for_date(date_record , account)
    loop  
    loop  
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Comment: What does your `datavault.account_active_for_date` function do? Why does it take two records as parameters? Does it return anything that you want to get as a result?

Comment: it returns bool, if the account was active for a particular date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to follow your business logic but syntax-wise your block needs correction. Please note that `d."date"` and `sad.id` are scalars (I assume a date and an integer) and not records.

```sql
do
$$
declare
    running_date date;
    running_id integer;
begin
    for running_date in select d."date" from datavault.dimdates_csv d loop
        for running_id in select sad.id from datavault.sat_account_details sad loop
            perform datavault.account_active_for_date(running_date, running_id);
        end loop; 
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

As far as I can see you are calling function `datavault.account_active_for_date` for every pair of `d."date"` and `sad.id`. If this is true then you can simply

```sql
select datavault.account_active_for_date(d."date", sad.id) 
from datavault.dimdates_csv d, datavault.sat_account_details sad;
```

and ignore the resultset.